# What is the difference between django.db.backends.dummy and django.db.backends.mysql?

Tags: mysql, django

What is the difference between django.db.backends.dummy and django.db.backends.mysql?
I find that someone use dummy and mysql, but I do not know their difference After searching.

Comment: Plus one, because you sound like a MySQL hater :)

Answer (score 4):

`django.db.backends.mysql` is used when the backend database is `MySQL`.

This is driven by the [database settings `Engine`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine)

```
ENGINE = `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`
```

Where as, `django.db.backends.dummy` is not a setting per say, but is triggered with

```
ENGINE = '' # The default setting for ENGINE
```

Moreover,

Digging into the [source code for `django.db.backends.dummy`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py#L4),

> Django uses this if the database ENGINE setting is empty (None or empty string).

Also, `dummy` raises an error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
                           "Please supply the ENGINE value. Check "
                           "settings documentation for more details.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`django.db.backends.dummy` is an unusable placeholder that always raises an `ImproperlyConfigured` error.

If a script or management command or whatever needs to run without a database available, then a "fake" engine backend can given from the [django-fake-database-backends](https://pypi.org/project/django-fake-database-backends/) package.

Alternatively, a throw-away sqlite database could be used, but that at minimum requires sqlite, which may not be desirable if running in a restrictive environment.