# mongoengine is not defined in setting.py though pip has it

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

mongoengine is not defined in setting.py though pip has it.

pip list show 
[pip list show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOnwz.png)

After serveral debugging, I think setting.py failed to import mongoengine. 
Then I tried to downgrade mongoengine, pymongo and upgrade django but nothing change.

The ErrorCode show

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("setting.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: setting .DATABASES is improperly configured.Pleas supply the ENGINE value. check ...

```
        INSTALLED_APPS = (
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            #mongo
        )

        MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

        )


        # Database -MONGODB
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
            }
        }

        from mongoengine import connect
        connect('employeedb', username='woosungchu', password='1234')

        SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
        SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoengine is not a django application, it's a normal python package so you don't need to specify it in setting.py.
To use mongoengine with django you just need to import it, exactly the same way you would use a normal python package.
The same applies for pymongo, it's a noraml python package.

You get this error because you didn't specify a backend.
You used django.db.backends.dummy which is not a real backend.
Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151100/what-is-the-difference-between-django-db-backends-dummy-and-django-db-backends-m) for more info.