# Django "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured" and "ImproperlyConfigured at /i18n/setlang/"

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I wrote a django web application and now I need to translate it to english. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/) but I keep getting this strange error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /i18n/setlang/ settings.DATABASES is
>   improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings
>   documentation for more details. Request Method:   POST Request
>   URL:  http://192.92.149.139:8000/i18n/setlang/ Django Version:    2.0.3
>   Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured Exception Value:
>   settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
>   value. Check settings documentation for more details. Exception
>   Location: /home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py
>   in complain, line 20 Python
>   Executable:   /home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/bin/python3.6 Python
>   Version:  3.6.4 Python Path:   ['/home/mwon/digitalocean/website_dev', 
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python36.zip', 
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6', 
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_styleguide-1.2.5-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Markdown-2.6.11-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4-0.0.1-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/duc_preprocess-1.0-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simple_cnlp-1.0-py3.6.egg',
>   '/home/mwon/venvs/arquivo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_mongoengine-0.3-py3.6.egg']
>   Server time:  Qua, 5 Set 2018 11:21:17 +0000

EDIT: and the settings.DATABASES:

```
{
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
        'OPTIONS': {},
        'TIME_ZONE': None,
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None
        }
    }
}
```

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/',include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('arquivo.urls')),
    prefix_default_language = True
)
```

and settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt'    
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
)
USE_I18N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale')
]
```

The translation seems to be working fine. The problem was when I included a form to select the language. I used the example code from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view):

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Please show your `settings.DATABASES` value

Comment: Ok, just edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151100/what-is-the-difference-between-django-db-backends-dummy-and-django-db-backends-m)

Comment: Second thought I can think is that maybe there is an issue with the datetime :/ Since I saw that you try globalization, there can be an issue with "pytz" :/ Have You installed such a thing ?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: Yeah, You should use a database like "Sqlite3" or "Mysql". To use these database engines which You don't use right now, you can read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases)

Comment: I'm using mongodb and everything was working ok until I started to implement this translation step.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was related with sessions. I'm using a MongoDB database with [Django-MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) and didn't turn on sessions support. So just added these two lines of code

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django_mongoengine.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django_mongoengine.sessions.BSONSerializer'
```

to `settings.py` and everything started to work fine.